# how to log echo from a docker-compose build process

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

There seems to be no way to show the current userID during build.

dockerfile

```
...
RUN echo $UID
```

run

```
docker-compose build --progress plain my_img
```

log

```
#7 [3/7] RUN echo $UID
#7 0.269
#7 DONE 0.3s
```

Comment: what echo $UID in the command line prints ? im tempted to say it is empty